# ROS2 FastRTPS services become unresponsive after a while

Tags: service, ros-humble

I am using ROS2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04 binary build, my current RMW implementation is the default for humble which is FastRTPS.

The problem I am facing now is that any ros service I have in Python or C++ becomes unresponsive after a random amount of time, sometimes restarting the daemon can help but not always.

Closing the service and turning it back up again solves the issue, but this is not feasible in a production environment.

Is there any way I can check the connectivity and restart it without closing the relative nodes?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? This sounds frustrating, but there are many potential levels at which your system could be looking connectivity. To be able to help you effectively enough information to reproduce the problem is necessary. Otherwise it's mostly going to be people guessing about your system and based on those assumptions guessing about what might be going wrong.

Comment: I am afraid I couldn't make a reproducible example, although I tried a simple service server and client on a different environment for several hours and it didn't give any error, maybe it's my environment.